# Showing progressbar in MapInfoWindow in Google Maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, progress-bar, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

I am working on an app, in which I would like to display progressbar in InfoWindow of google maps v2. I have managed to customize the InfoWindow using a customized class MapInfoWindowAdapter.

Now, I want to show the progressbar on that InfoWindow as such used in the Uber map, to show progress.

For that, I have tried two things

1. Using progressbar in info_window_layout file
2. Using gif image for loader to show the progress, by animating its frames one by one.

Both of them resulted in a static image, i.e, showing no progress at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply animation to the `InfoWindow`, for one simple reason. what you see in the `InfoWindow` is not the layout you defined but an image that was drawn from it. meaning you can'y manipulate this `InfoWindow`.

From Google's documentation:

> **Note:** The info window that is drawn is not a live view. The view is rendered as an image (using `View.draw(Canvas)`) at the time it is returned. This means that any subsequent changes to the view will not be reflected by the info window on the map. To update the info window later (e.g., after an image has loaded), call `showInfoWindow()`. Furthermore, the info window will not respect any of the interactivity typical for a normal view such as touch or gesture events. However you can listen to a generic click event on the whole info window as described in the section below.

Comment: But, I have checked the Uber app, and in that, it is using loader in InfoWindow. I just need the exact thing like that.

Comment: what you see in the Uber app is not a marker on the map, it's located above the map layout... so it's not directly connected to the map fragment.